# If $a<A<a'$ and $b<B<b'$ then why is $\frac{a'}{b'}<\frac{A}{B}<\frac{a'}{b}$ true?

Tags: inequality

I'm reading a book on Higher algebra in which the author states that:—

**if $a$, $a'$, $b$, $b'$ are given numbers and $A$, $B$ are any numbers such that $a<A<a'$ and $b<B<b'$ then $\frac{a'}{b'}<\frac{A}{B}<\frac{a'}{b}$ for all numbers being positive.**

I think there is a typo.

I know about this property, $ab<AB<a'b'$ for all positive numbers . Also, $\frac{1}{b'}<\frac{1}{B}<\frac{1}{b}$ for all positive numbers.

I think the above inequality should be $\frac{a}{b'}<\frac{A}{B}<\frac{a'}{b}$.

*Am I correct?*

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a typo and you interpret correctly.  Your two properties combine.  $a < A < a'$ and $\frac 1{b'}<\frac 1B < \frac 1b$ would combinte $a\frac 1{b'} < A\frac 1B< a'\frac 1b$ so your inequality is certainly correct.  The book's example doesn't follow and we can find a counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. From $0<a<A$ and $0<B<b'$ we obtain $0<a<A$ and $0<\frac{1}{b'}<\frac{1}{B}$. Hence $\frac{a}{b'}<\frac{A}{B}$. The inequality $\frac{A}{B}<\frac{a'}{b}$ can be obtained in a similar manner.

The statement that $\frac{a'}{b'}<\frac{A}{B}$ is false, as shown by the counterexample $A=2<4=a'$ and $B=3<4=b'$.